# Use Numpy to iterate through columns and feed to function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to accomplish the following and am stuck:

1. Import csv file into numpy array
2. Iterate over column of the numpy array, and for each column, have an array of the values
3. Pass that to a function

I currently have:

```
def csv_to_array(file):
    # Open the file, and load it in delimiting on the ',' for a comma separated value file
    data = open(file, 'r')
    data = numpy.loadtxt(data, delimiter=',')

    # Loop through the data in the array
    for index in range(len(data)):
        # Utilize a try catch to try and convert to float, if it can't convert to float, converts to 0
        try:
            data[index] = [float(x) for x in data[index]]
        except ValueError:
            data[index] = 0

    # Return the now type-formatted data
    randomize_data(data)
    return data

def randomize_data(csv):
    csv = numpy.random.shuffle(csv)
    return csv

def main():
    test = csv_to_array('ss.csv') 
    features = numpy.asarray(test.tolist()[:-1])
    # for column in features.T:
    #     print("BREAK")
    #     print(column)
    #     currPerf = k_means(column,3)

main()
```

Therefore, when I call `test=csv_to_array('ss.csv')`. For what it is worth, ss.csv is the iris data set with each class replaced by 0, 1, or 2 (that I later remove). I get the following:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 0. ]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2 0. ]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 0. ]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 0. ]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2 0. ]
 [5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 0. ]
 [4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3 0. ]
 [5.  3.4 1.5 0.2 0. ]
 [4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2 0. ]
 [4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1 0. ]
 [5.4 3.7 1.5 0.2 0. ]
 [4.8 3.4 1.6 0.2 0. ]
 [4.8 3.  1.4 0.1 0. ]
 [4.3 3.  1.1 0.1 0. ]
 [5.8 4.  1.2 0.2 0. ]
 [5.7 4.4 1.5 0.4 0. ]
...]
```

What I am aiming to do is be able to create a variable, say `test_columns`, and iterate over the above numpy array and one-by-one append to `test_columns`

```
So Iteration 1: <br />
`test_columns = 
[5.1]
[4.9]
[4.7]
[4.6]
[5. ]
...]
`

Iteration 2: <br />
`test_columns = 
[5.1 3.5]
[4.9 3. ]
[4.7 3.2 ]
[4.6 1.3 ]
[5.  3.6 ]
...]
`

Iteration 3: <br />
`test_columns = 
[5.1 3.5 1.4]
[4.9 3. 1.4]
[4.7 3.2 1.3]
[4.6 1.3 1.5]
[5.  3.6 1.4]
...]
`
```

Etc. How am I able to loop through a numpy array, one column at a time, appending to a new numpy array. The new numpy array will be evaluated in a further function.

I have tried `for column in features.T` to transpose the array and I am not getting expected results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `loadtxt` as you use it returns a float dtype array.  It will raise an error if there are any values that it could not convert.  So most of `csv_to_array` isn't needed.  But look at `data` yourself.

Comment: `data[:,[0]`, `data[:,[0,1]]`, `data[:,[0,1,2]]` or `data[:,:3]` will give you various subsets of the columns of `data`.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, it seems that you are correct that the proper slice notation here does allow me to accomplish the goal (specifically `print(test[:, [0]])`. However, how is it possible for me to loop over the entire data set doing this one-by-one, as the size of my dataset may change (it won't always just be the iris test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` comes with the ability to do this this via `numpy.hsplit(array, column)`. Full documentation is at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html but essentially in iteration 1 you would use: `test_columns = numpy.hsplit(test, 1)`, and then next iteration: `test_columns = numpy.hsplit(test, 2)`, etc.. You may need to implement another step of indexing depending on how it returns your array (I'm not an expert by any means), but I'm pretty confident this is the method you are looking for!

**@EDIT**

Here is an example code where I split an array into columns:

import numpy as np

```
my_array = np.array([
    [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 0.],
    [4.9, 3.,  1.4, 0.2, 0.],
    [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 0.],
    [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 0.],
    [5.,  3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 0.],
    [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, 0.],
    [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3, 0.],
    [5.,  3.4, 1.5, 0.2, 0.],
    [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2, 0.]])

test1 = np.hsplit(my_array, np.array([1, 1]))[0]
print(test1)
```

> Which prints [[5.1][4.9][4.7][4.6][5. ][5.4][4.6][5. ][4.4]]

You can change it to `test1 = np.hsplit(my_array, np.array([2, 1]))[0]` to correctly slice the first two columns. It appears the second argument works better as a numpy array than an `int()`, and you do want to slice the `[0]`'th element of what is returned to get it to work correctly, as it will return some garbage array as well which for your purposes should be disregarded.

To implement this on a data set automatically you can replace the last two lines of code above with:

```
columns = my_array.shape[1]

for column_index in range(1, columns + 1):
    test = np.hsplit(my_array, np.array([column_index, 1]))[0]
    print(test)
```

Comment: Thank you @Reedinationer for the suggestion. hsplit doesn't seem to be doing anything to help at the moment, but I will keep trying, it looks like it may be promising. thank you

Comment: @JerryM. I've edited my post to include an example of how it should be used! Hopefully the edit makes it clear how to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for that @Reedinationer. I see what you mean now, I misunderstood the documentation.
However, my concern is that I will not always know the dimension of my dataset (ie how many columns), so I am looking for a solution that will allow me to loop through and do what you just did without explicitly calling out which columns to present, since I won't know how many columns there are.

Comment: @JerryM. OK I gave a method for how to loop through an array of arbitrary row length!

Comment: Thank you so much @Reedinationer, this seems to work regardless of row or column length. This is what I needed. Would you mind helping me understand? For index in the range 1->length+1 (to make sure all columns are iterated through), we are splitting the array [index,1][0]. What does that mean?

Comment: @JerryM. Glad I could help! If this answered your question it'd be great if you accept it as the answer XD. Yes, `range(1, columns + 1)` is used to iterate through all the columns, and there is also a 0 indexed column which returns `[]`. As for the `np.array([column_index, 1]))[0]` I'll start with the `[0]`. This basically indexes the result to be what you are looking for. You can omit this part and see that it prints 2 other arrays as well and I'm not sure what they mean. The `[column, 1]` bit was from documentation where they used np.array([3, 6]). Sadly your guess is as good as mine here.